# How to get a workflow diagram in Alfresco?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I have created a workflow in Alfresco, but when I call the following service, after having started the workflow, to get a diagram for the workflow there is no diagram.

/alfresco/service/api/workflow-instances/{workflow_instance_id}/diagram

How do I get Alfresco to generate this diagram?

I am using Alfresco version 4.2.e.

Comment: Are you substituting your workflow instance ID into the URL?

Comment: Yes, I have specified the correct workflow id. If I call it like this: /alfresco/service/api/workflow-instances/activiti$5830, I get the information about the workflow, but when I add /diagram, I get a '404 Requested resource not available'

Comment: Is that your custom workflow instance or out of box workflow instance?

Comment: It is a custom workflow

Comment: I just dit a quick test, created a workflow (through the UI) once I clicked on the View Diagram button which showed me the diagrem. Second workflow started it and directly addressed this url in the browser which also showed me a diagram http://<server>/share/proxy/alfresco/api/workflow-instances/activiti$265/diagram . So probably there is something wrong why you can't see the diagram. Go the the workflow history and click the view diagram button and post the result.

Comment: A useful blog about showing the workflow diagram in the document-details: http://www.bataon.com/blogs/amandaluniz/workflow-status-diagram-document-details